# Questions about installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 server

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, gnome

I've got some question during the installation of Ubuntu 14.04.2 server.

- if I choose catalan as the language, when the installation finishes, the screen becames black and there is nothing to do. Is this normal?
- if I choose spanish, the installation seems to go ok. After this, I try to install gnome (I need desktop, I'm new in Ubuntu):
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get upgrade
- sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install
  But I think it may be a reduced version of the desktop. The problem is that there is no way to execute terminal, and for this reason I can't solve some warnings I've got during the installation.

Please, can anybody confirm if the gnome installation is correct?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a complete GNOME Shell desktop, you can use the package `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

But then I ask myself the question why you chose the server image. If you want to use a graphical interface, why don't you use a desktop image instead. There even is one that features the GNOME Shell as its default desktop: [Ubuntu GNOME](https://ubuntugnome.org/).

A full list of official flavors can be found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours), but virtually any desktop out there, from minimalist tiling window managers like i3wm to full-featured and hardware-demanding desktops like GNOME Shell or Unity, can be installed on Ubuntu.

The major (and after installation only) difference between the server and desktop is in fact the default lack of a graphical desktop in a server installation: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F).

One difference during installation is that the desktop image brings a graphical installation utility called *Ubiquity*, and I think language/localisation installation is much easier.

So make your life easier and use a desktop image, if possible. You can still run software servers on the machine, independently whether you chose a server or desktop image for installation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I'm a Windows user. Some months ago I installed in a costumer company, owncloud. But now, there is no more support for windows environment. For this reason we decided to install a server with linux.
Do you mean it's not necessary to install the server version, with desktop is enough for me. Sure my life would be easier